# Open installed own app from other app

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am trying to open my android app from another app(example gmail app) when user clicks the specified url.

I have succeed with clicking a sample url , for example

```
    <data
        android:host="showonthecloud.com"
        android:scheme="http" 

        />
</intent-filter>
```

checked by myself by sending a mail to me with the url http://showonthecloud.com

But the url would be http://username.showonthecloud.com

The username is can only get after logged into the app. How could I replace the username dynamically in Manifest file?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got solution

Adding *. before the it we can achieve it.

```
<data
    android:host="*.showonthecloud.com"
    android:scheme="http" 

    />
```